# Async function don't await for result in Unity

Tags: c#, database, firebase, unity-game-engine, lambda

i would like to wait with next function to finish previous one first. But i have return before it is finished. Here is code:

```
private async Task SetupPlayerDatabase()
{
    Task<string> signInWithPlayGames = SignIn.SignInWithPlayGames();
    userId = await signInWithPlayGames;
    Debug.Log("USER ID: " + userId);
}
```

and the sceound class:

```
and SignInWithPlayGames:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class SignIn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static string userId;

    void Awake () {
        // Initialize Play Games Configuration and Activate it.
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().RequestServerAuthCode(false /*forceRefresh*/).Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        //Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: Play Games Configuration initialized");
    }

                // HERE IS THIS FUNCTION ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ 

    public static async Task<string> SignInWithPlayGames () {
        await Task.Run(() => {
        Debug.LogError("SignIn.SignInWithGooglePlay Task is running");
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance; // Sign In and Get a server auth code.
        UnityEngine.Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            if (!success) {
                Debug.LogError ("SignInOnClick: Failed to Sign into Play Games Services.");
                return;
            }
            string authCode = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCode))
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick: Signed into Play Games Services but failed to get the server auth code.");
                return;
            }
            //Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: Auth code is: {0}", authCode); // Use Server Auth Code to make a credential
            Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(authCode); // Sign In to Firebase with the credential
            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.LogError ("SignInOnClick was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
            userId = newUser.UserId;
            // i would like to return userId here, but i cannot
            });
        });
        });
        Debug.LogError("SignIn.SignInWithGooglePlay return: " + userId);
        return userId; // here i return before it have value
    }
}
```

Debugg shows me that first i had `return userId;` and after this i have `userId = newUser.UserId;`. So first i have return empty string and next userId get value.

I cannot write `return userId;` one line under `userId = newUser.UserId;` becouse it's lambda and return void.

How can i fix it to finish this function in good place and moment? To return `userId` after make value in this string?

Comment: My advice is returning the userId instead of to set that in the local variable, by doing that you will be creating a Task<string>, by await it you will have the user id asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement on your code will execute before the task ends because the task that you are creating with `Task.Run` has no result. By changing the task to return a string i.e. create a `Task<string>` as bellow, it will wait for a result before continuing to next line.

```
public static async Task<string> SignInWithPlayGames () {
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Task.Run(() => {
        Debug.LogError("SignIn.SignInWithGooglePlay Task is running");
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance; // Sign In and Get a server auth code.
        UnityEngine.Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            if (!success) {
                Debug.LogError ("SignInOnClick: Failed to Sign into Play Games Services.");
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
            string authCode = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCode))
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick: Signed into Play Games Services but failed to get the server auth code.");
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
            //Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: Auth code is: {0}", authCode); // Use Server Auth Code to make a credential
            Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(authCode); // Sign In to Firebase with the credential
            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.LogError ("SignInOnClick was canceled.");
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
            tcs.SetResult(newUser.UserId);
            });
        });
    });
    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Explain why this works, and why it is better than the OP's code.

Comment: Thank you for the note @RobertHarvey, I improved the answer.

Comment: It's pretty near to work, but two firsts `return null` have errors:
`Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value`

Comment: @AnotherKenKesey Check the edited version, I believe you will need to use the TaskCompletionSource to achieve what you need. For more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

I have solution. I had to split authorization and method to waiting for it because authorization cannot by called from non-main thread (in Unity). Now it's works and look like this:

```
private async Task SetupPlayerDatabase()
{
    SignIn signIn = new SignIn();
    Task<string> checkAuthorizedCorrect = signIn.CheckAuthorizedCorrect();
    userId = await checkAuthorizedCorrect;
    Debug.Log("USER ID: " + userId);
}
```

and:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using Firebase.Auth;


public class SignIn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool playerIsAuthorized;
    private static string userId;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        // Initialize Play Games Configuration and Activate it.
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().RequestServerAuthCode(false /*forceRefresh*/).Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: Play Games Configuration initialized");
        SignInWithPlayGames();
    }

public async Task<string> CheckAuthorizedCorrect () {
    await Task.Run(() => {
        while (playerIsAuthorized == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waiting for userId");
        }
    });
    return userId;
}

public static void SignInWithPlayGames () {
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        Debug.Log("Sign In and Get a server auth code.");
        UnityEngine.Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            if (!success) {
                Debug.LogError ("SignInOnClick: Failed to Sign into Play Games Services.");
                return;
            }
            string authCode = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCode))
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick: Signed into Play Games Services but failed to get the server auth code.");
                return;
            }
            Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: Auth code is: {0}", authCode); // Use Server Auth Code to make a credential
            Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(authCode); // Sign In to Firebase with the credential
            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.LogError ("SignInOnClick was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
            userId = newUser.UserId;
            playerIsAuthorized = true;
            });
        });
    }
}
```